# How to read Avro file in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, avro, pyspark

I am writing a spark job using python. However, I need to read in a whole bunch of avro files.

[This](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/avro_inputformat.py) is the closest solution that I have found in Spark's example folder. However, you need to submit this python script using spark-submit. In the command line of spark-submit, you can specify the driver-class, in that case, all your avrokey, avrovalue class will be located.

```
avro_rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(
        path,
        "org.apache.avro.mapreduce.AvroKeyInputFormat",
        "org.apache.avro.mapred.AvroKey",
        "org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable",
        keyConverter="org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter",
        conf=conf)
```

In my case, I need to run everything within the Python script, I have tried to create an environment variable to include the jar file, finger cross Python will add the jar to the path but clearly it is not, it is giving me unexpected class error.

```
os.environ['SPARK_SUBMIT_CLASSPATH'] = "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.1.0-1.cdh5.1.0.p0.53/lib/spark/examples/lib/spark-examples_2.10-1.0.0-cdh5.1.0.jar"
```

Can anyone help me how to read avro file in one python script?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4.0**

You can use [built-in Avro support](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html). The API is backwards compatible with the `spark-avro` package, with a few additions (most notably `from_avro` / `to_avro` function).

Please note that module is not bundled with standard Spark binaries and has to be included using `spark.jars.packages` or equivalent mechanism.

See also [Pyspark 2.4.0, read avro from kafka with read stream - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54693110/10465355)

**Spark < 2.4.0**

You can use [`spark-avro`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro) library. First lets create an example dataset:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter

schema_string ='''{"namespace": "example.avro",
 "type": "record",
 "name": "KeyValue",
 "fields": [
     {"name": "key", "type": "string"},
     {"name": "value",  "type": ["int", "null"]}
 ]
}'''

schema = avro.schema.parse(schema_string)

with open("kv.avro", "w") as f, DataFileWriter(f, DatumWriter(), schema) as wrt:
    wrt.append({"key": "foo", "value": -1})
    wrt.append({"key": "bar", "value": 1})
```

Reading it using `spark-csv` is as simple as this:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("kv.avro")
df.show()

## +---+-----+
## |key|value|
## +---+-----+
## |foo|   -1|
## |bar|    1|
## +---+-----+
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of `pyspark` with `from_avro` ?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the built-in `from_avro` and `to_avro` functions are not yet available in _PySpark_ 2.4.x. Looks like these are being added in PySpark 3.0, as per the `@since` tags [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/avro/functions.py#L29-L67).

Comment: @mattjw [Pyspark 2.4.0, read avro from kafka with read stream - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54693110/10465355)

Answer (score 6):

The former solution requires to install a third-party Java dependency, which is not something most Python devs are happy with. But you don't really need an external library if all you want to do is parse your Avro files with a given schema. You can just read the binary files and parse them with your favorite python Avro package.

For instance, this is how you can load Avro files using `fastavro`:

```
from io import BytesIO
import fastavro

schema = {
    ...
}

rdd = sc.binaryFiles("/path/to/dataset/*.avro")\
    .flatMap(lambda args: fastavro.reader(BytesIO(args[1]), reader_schema=schema))

print(rdd.collect())
```

Answer (score 2):

For Spark < 2.4.0, PySpark can create the dataframe by reading the avro file and its respective schema(.avsc) without any external python module by using the JAR "com.databricks.spark.avro" and python's "subprocess" module

Below is the solution:

```
avsc_location = hdfs://user/test/test.avsc
avro_location = hdfs://user/test/test.avro

#use subprocess module
import subproccess as SP

load_avsc_file = SP.Popen(["hdfs", "dfs", "-cat", avsc_location], stdout=SP.PIPE, stderr=SP.PIPE)
(avsc_file_output, avsc_file_error) = load_avsc_file.communicate()

avro_df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").option("avroSchema", avsc_file_output).load(avro_location)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can read the Avro files data into spark dataframe. Refer this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/read-avro-files.html) and below code to read Avro file using PySpark.

```
df = spark.read.format("avro").load("<avro_file_location>")
```