# Installing spark-avro

Tags: pyspark, spark-avro

I'm trying to read avro files in pyspark.
Found out from [How to read Avro file in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29759893/how-to-read-avro-file-in-pyspark) that spark-avro is the best way to do that but I can't figure out how to install that from their [Github repo](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro). There's no downloadable jar, do I build it myself? How?

It's Spark 1.6 (pyspark) running on a cluster. I didn't set it up so don't know much about the configs but I have sudo access so I guess I should be able to install stuff. But the machine doesn't have direct internet access so need to manually copy and install stuff to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add `spark-avro` as a package when running `pyspark` or `spark-submit`: https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro#with-spark-shell-or-spark-submit but this will require internet access on driver (driver will then distribute all files to the executors).

If you have no internet access on a driver you will need to build `spark-avro` yourself to a fat jar:

```
git clone https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro.git
cd spark-avro
# If you are using spark package other than newest, 
# checkout appropriate tag based on table in spark-avro README, 
# for example for spark 1.6:
# git checkout v2.0.1 
./build/sbt assembly
```

Then test it using pyspark shell:

```
./bin/pyspark --jars ~/git/spark-avro/target/scala-2.11/spark-avro-assembly-3.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

>>> spark.range(10).write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("/tmp/output")
>>> spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("/tmp/output").show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  7|
|  8|
|  9|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
|  0|
|  1|
|  5|
|  6|
+---+
```

Comment: How do I build a fat jar for spark-avro?

Comment: Clone `spark-avro` repository and run `build/sbt assembly`

Comment: It says 'Attempting to fetch sbt
Our attempt to download sbt locally to build/sbt-launch-0.13.11.jar failed. Please install sbt manually from http://www.scala-sbt.org/`

Comment: Build the fat jar on system that is connected to internet. Then copy file to driver and start spark with `--jars`.

Comment: Stuck at `Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.11 ...
downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.10.6/scala-library-2.10.6.jar ...` for  a long time...
my internet is fine otherwise

Comment: Got the jar and tried to run again but got this `Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.avro. Please use Spark package http://spark-packages.org/package/databricks/spark-avro`

Comment: Are you sure you include `--jars path/to/fat.jar` in command?

Comment: Yeah, I added the jar from the target folder and that's when the error changed to what I put in my previous comment. Before adding that jar it was some other error.

Comment: I just tested the solution with spark-2.0.1 and spark-avro from master and edited comment to give you more details. Please ensure your steps matches instructions.

Comment: I got it to work by building the fat jar on the 'branch-2.0' branch because I have an older spark version. mucho gracias! thanks for all your help!

Comment: It's also a good idea to move the created jar file to jars directory `sudo mv /home/hadoop/spark-avro/target/scala-2.11/spark-avro-assembly-4.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar $SPARK_HOME/jars/`

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-avro_2.11/${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-avro_2.11-${SPARK_VERSION}.jar -P $SPARK_HOME/jars/                                                        

echo spark.executor.extraClassPath $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-avro_2.11-$SPARK_VERSION.jar >>  /usr/local/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf                                                                    

echo spark.driver.extraClassPath $SPARK_HOME/jars/spark-avro_2.11-$SPARK_VERSION.jar >>  /usr/local/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```