# Reading avro messages from Kafka in spark streaming/structured streaming

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using pyspark for the first time.
Spark Version : 2.3.0
Kafka Version : 2.2.0

I have a kafka producer which sends nested data in avro format and I am trying to write code in spark-streaming/ structured streaming in pyspark which will deserialize the avro coming from kafka into dataframe do transformations write it in parquet format into s3.
I was able to find avro converters in spark/scala but support in pyspark has not yet been added. How do I convert the same in pyspark.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As like you mentioned , Reading Avro message from Kafka and parsing through pyspark, don't  have direct libraries for the same . But we can read/parsing Avro message by writing small wrapper and call that function as UDF in your pyspark streaming code as below .

**Reference :** 
[Pyspark 2.4.0, read avro from kafka with read stream - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693110/pyspark-2-4-0-read-avro-from-kafka-with-read-stream-python)

**Note:** Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide".

**Refererence:** https://spark-test.github.io/pyspark-coverage-site/pyspark_sql_avro_functions_py.html

**Spark-Submit :**

[adjust the package versions to match spark/avro version based  installation]

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/bin/pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3 --conf spark.ui.port=4064
```

**Pyspark Streaming Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
import json
import csv
import time
import os

#  Spark Streaming context :

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('streamingdata').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

#  Kafka Topic Details :

KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "topicname"
KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "topic_to_hdfs"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = 'localhost.com:9093'

#  Creating  readstream DataFrame :

df = spark.readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS) \
     .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS) \
     .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
     .option("failOnDataLoss" ,"false")\
     .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL")\
     .option("kafka.client.id" ,"MCI-CIL")\
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka")\
     .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "/path/kafka_trust.jks") \
     .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", "changeit") \
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.keytab","/path/bdpda.headless.keytab") \
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.principal","bdpda") \
     .load()


df1 = df.selectExpr( "CAST(value AS STRING)")

df1.registerTempTable("test")


# Deserilzing the Avro code function

from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column 
def from_avro(col): 
     jsonFormatSchema = """
                    {
                     "type": "record",
                     "name": "struct",
                     "fields": [
                       {"name": "col1", "type": "long"},
                       {"name": "col2", "type": "string"}
                                ]
                     }"""
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context 
    avro = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.avro
    f = getattr(getattr(avro, "package$"), "MODULE$").from_avro
    return Column(f(_to_java_column(col), jsonFormatSchema))


spark.udf.register("JsonformatterWithPython", from_avro)

squared_udf = udf(from_avro)
df1 = spark.table("test")
df2 = df1.select(squared_udf("value"))

#  Declaring the Readstream Schema DataFrame :

df2.coalesce(1).writeStream \
   .format("parquet") \
   .option("checkpointLocation","/path/chk31") \
   .outputMode("append") \
   .start("/path/stream/tgt31")


ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Why do you need df5 and df1 to be the same thing? Alsop, as it commented on the answer you linked, this does not work for Confluent Schema Registry Avro data

Comment: Thanks for sharing your comments . You are right !! df5 is not required and corrected that code.As In question not been mentioned about confluent registry given general Avro format handled code

Comment: Right, but that's rarely what is put in Kafka, in my experience

Comment: FYI Please , This code , I have implemented in Cloudra environment with classic Apache Kafka

Comment: Okay, fine, then you're not using a Schema Registry? Confluent doesn't use anything other than Apache Kafka...

Comment: above code doesn't support backward compatibility. Do not use it if you have a case of reading records with an older schema.