# How to get Avro data from Confluent Schema Registry in String format from kafka in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, avro, spark-structured-streaming, confluent-schema-registry

I am reading data from Kafka in spark(structured streaming) But Data getting in spark from kafka in spark is not in string format.
Spark: 2.3.4

Kafka Data format:

```
{"Patient_ID":316,"Name":"Richa","MobileNo":{"long":7049123177},"BDate":{"int":740},"Gender":"female"}
```

Here is the code for kafka to spark  structured streaming:

```
#  spark-submit --jars kafka-clients-0.10.0.1.jar --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11:2.3.4,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 /home/kinjalpatel/kafka_sppark.py
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import json
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json, col, struct
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, DoubleType
from confluent_kafka.avro.serializer.message_serializer import MessageSerializer
from confluent_kafka.avro.cached_schema_registry_client import CachedSchemaRegistryClient
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column

sc = SparkContext()
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
spark = SparkSession(sc)
schema_registry_client = CachedSchemaRegistryClient(
url='http://localhost:8081')
serializer = MessageSerializer(schema_registry_client)
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", "mysql-01-Patient") \
  .option("partition.assignment.strategy", "range") \
  .option("valueConverter", "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.AvroWrapperToJavaConverter") \
  .load()
df.printSchema()
mta_stream=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)", "CAST(topic AS STRING)", "CAST(partition AS STRING)", "CAST(offset AS STRING)", "CAST(timestamp AS STRING)", "CAST(timestampType AS STRING)")
mta_stream.printSchema()
qry = mta_stream.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").start()
qry.awaitTermination()
```

This is the output I get:

```
+----+--------------------+----------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
| key|               value|           topic|partition|offset|           timestamp|timestampType|
+----+--------------------+----------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
|null|�
Richa���...|mysql-01-Patient|        0|   160|2019-12-27 11:56:...|            0|
+----+--------------------+----------------+---------+------+--------------------+-------------+
```

How to get `value` column in string format?

Comment: You are clearly getting something, though with the formatting it is hard to see what. Could you be more specific which part looks different than expected (what you see vs what you expect)?

Comment: Are you using Confluent Schema Registry? Are records avro-encoded (with or without Confluent Schema Registry)?

Comment: Yes data are avro encoded @JacekLaskowski

Comment: Need to get data from kafka in spark in readable format @DennisJaheruddin

Comment: if I do 
    mta_stream=df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
then I get output as :
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|�
Richa���...|
+--------------------+

Comment: You ARE getting String Format. You need to check you incoming Encoding.

Comment: Data stored in kafka is in avro format @MehdiLAMRANI

Comment: You need to `deserialize` the `value` field to see the message. Can use confluent's `KafkaAvroDeserializer`

Comment: You need to write your own UDF, not `CAST AS STRING`. It's also not clear if you need AvroWrapperToJavaConverter

Comment: https://github.com/AbsaOSS/ABRiS

Answer (score 0):

from [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html#to_avro-and-from_avro)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._

// `from_avro` requires Avro schema in JSON string format.
val jsonFormatSchema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./examples/src/main/resources/user.avsc"    )))

val df = spark
    .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()


val output = df
  .select(from_avro('value, jsonFormatSchema) as 'user)
  .where("user.favorite_color == \"red\"")
  .select(to_avro($"user.name") as 'value)

val query = output
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic2")
  .start()
```

from [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/structured-streaming/avro-dataframe.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro._
import org.apache.avro.SchemaBuilder

// When reading the key and value of a Kafka topic, decode the
// binary (Avro) data into structured data.
// The schema of the resulting DataFrame is: <key: string, value: int>
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", servers)
  .option("subscribe", "t")
  .load()
  .select(
    from_avro($"key", SchemaBuilder.builder().stringType()).as("key"),
    from_avro($"value", SchemaBuilder.builder().intType()).as("value"))
```

Comment: This is only available from Databricks platform, not just any Spark consumer

Comment: Yes, I am. You can find issues on the spark-avro github page saying as much. Also, spark-avro as of Spark 2.4 does not support Confluent Schema Registry, so I suggest you try your answers before copying from the documentation

Answer (score -1):

For Reading Avro message from Kafka topic and parsing in pyspark structured streaming, don't have direct libraries for the same . But we can read/parsing Avro message by writing small wrapper and call that function as UDF in your pyspark streaming code.

**Please refer:**

[Reading avro messages from Kafka in spark streaming/structured streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948257/reading-avro-messages-from-kafka-in-spark-streaming-structured-streaming/59415957#59415957)

Comment: Where is your answer using the Schema Registry?