# pyspark: avro deserialize function on dataframe fails as it expects list

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, deserialization, confluent-schema-registry

avro deserialize function expects bytes in a list and fails while applying on a data frame. Only works with collect() but driver/master is running out of memory

Using spark version 2.3.3 with python 3.6.8
dataframe is being created from Hive table select which has avro serialized message.
Then I am using https://github.com/Landoop/python-serializers.git since it supports avro deserialize using confluent schema registry on python 3.x

Tried applying the deserialize function on dataframe and it fails.
Only works if I df.collect() and use for loop to deserialize every entry or works if I convert df into rdd.map and deserialize every row. 
Both these cases only work in test, in prod it either OOM or run forever on a 10GB hive data running on 5node 30GB,8cpu servers.

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
....
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table1")
unbase_df = df.select(unbase64(df.mycolumn1))

client = SchemaRegistryClient(url='1.2.3.4:1234')
serializer = MessageSerializer(client)

##attempt 1##FAILS##
decode_df = df.select(serializer.decode_message('mycolumn1'))
###->ERROR -> 
##attempt 2##FAILS##
decode_df_2 = df.select(serializer.decode_message(b'mycolumn1'))

##attempt 3##WORKS BUT OOM with high volume on master(drivermanager)##
unbase_collect = unbase_df.collect()
decode_list = [serializer.decode_message(msg.mycolumn1) for msg in unbase_collect]

##attempt 4##WORKS BUT RUNS FOR EVER##
def avrodecoder(row):
    decoded_row = serializer.decode_message(row['mycolumn1'])
    return decoded_row

decode_rdd = unbase_df.select("*").rdd.map(avrodecoder)

## After #3 or #4 works I convert back to dataframe with schema
schema = StructType([
    StructField("1column",  StructType([
.......
    StructField("ncolumn", StringType()])

decode_df = spark.createDataFrame(decode_rdd,schema)
```

Error message in case of #attempt 1

> ````
> in decode_message(self, message)
>     185             raise SerializerError("message is too small to decode")
>     186
> --> 187         with ContextBytesIO(message) as payload:
>     188             magic, schema_id = struct.unpack('>bI', payload.read(5))
>     189             if magic != MAGIC_BYTE:
>
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'```
>
> Error message in case of #attempt 2
> ```.....python3.6/site-packages/datamountaineer/schemaregistry/serializers/MessageSerializer.py
> in decode_message(self, message)
>     188             magic, schema_id = struct.unpack('>bI', payload.read(5))
>     189             if magic != MAGIC_BYTE:
> --> 190                 raise SerializerError("message does not start with magic byte")
>     191             decoder_func = self._get_decoder_func(schema_id, payload)
>     192             return decoder_func(payload)
>
> SerializerError: the message does not start with a magic byte ```
> ````

1. How can I avro deserialize via confluent schema registry directly on a dataframe
2. How can I make sure all the transformations are executed only on workers/executors
3. How can I make it work efficiently enough it doesn't OOM or run 5,6+ hours for <10GB of data
4. Don't understand the logic behind why 'Yarn Pending Memory' graph shows that in both working cases it climbs up to 7+TB or even higher

Answer (score 0):

Before you can apply a plain Python function on a `Column`, you have to convert it to an User Defined Function (`UDF`):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf(decoded_row_schema)
def avrodecoder(row):
    decoded_row = serializer.decode_message(row['mycolumn1'])
    return decoded_row
```

where `decoded_row_schema` describes the shape of the returned object.

However if you use a current (>= 2.4.0) release, that might not be necessary at all - [Pyspark 2.4.0, read avro from kafka with read stream - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54693110)

Comment: I tried you second suggest spark_avro on Spark 2.4.x. Defined from_avro function similar to your example. But it errors out
unbase64_df.show(1)

|[00 00 00 01 76 4...|

```
avro_type_struct = """{....}"""

avro_df = unbase64_raw_df.select(from_avro('unbase_raw_event',avro_type_struct))
```
ERROR
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: ..while calling o77.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 17 in stage 24.0 : Lost task 17.3 in stage 24.0 (TID 347, master, executor 2): org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -1