# Pyspark 2.4.3, Read Avro format message from Kafka - Pyspark Structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, spark-avro

I am trying to read Avro messages from Kafka, using PySpark 2.4.3. Based on the below stack over flow link , Am able to covert into Avro format (to_avro) and code is working as expected. but from_avro is not working and getting below issue.Are there any other modules that support reading avro messages streamed from Kafka? This is Cloudra distribution environment.
Please suggest on this .

**Reference :** 
[Pyspark 2.4.0, read avro from kafka with read stream - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54693110/pyspark-2-4-0-read-avro-from-kafka-with-read-stream-python)

**Environment Details :**

Spark :

```
 / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.1 (default, Jul 24 2019 04:52:09)
```

Pyspark :

pyspark  2.4.3

**Spark_submit :**

```
/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/bin/pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.3 --conf spark.ui.port=4064
```

**to_avro**

```
from pyspark.sql.column import Column, _to_java_column 

def from_avro(col, jsonFormatSchema): 
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context 
    avro = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.avro
    f = getattr(getattr(avro, "package$"), "MODULE$").from_avro
    return Column(f(_to_java_column(col), jsonFormatSchema)) 


def to_avro(col): 
    sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context 
    avro = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.sql.avro
    f = getattr(getattr(avro, "package$"), "MODULE$").to_avro
    return Column(f(_to_java_column(col))) 
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, struct


avro_type_struct = """
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "struct",
  "fields": [
    {"name": "col1", "type": "long"},
    {"name": "col2", "type": "string"}
  ]
}"""


df = spark.range(10).select(struct(
    col("id"),
    col("id").cast("string").alias("id2")
).alias("struct"))
avro_struct_df = df.select(to_avro(col("struct")).alias("avro"))
avro_struct_df.show(3)
+----------+
|      avro|
+----------+
|[00 02 30]|
|[02 02 31]|
|[04 02 32]|
+----------+
only showing top 3 rows
```

**from_avro:**

```
avro_struct_df.select(from_avro("avro", avro_type_struct)).show(3)
```

**Error Message :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 993, in select
    jdf = self._jdf.select(self._jcols(*cols))
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/2.6.1.0-129/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o61.select.
: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()Lorg/apache/avro/LogicalType;
        at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$.toSqlTypeHelper(SchemaConverters.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.avro.SchemaConverters$$anonfun$1.apply(SchemaConverters.scala:82)
```

Answer (score 2):

Spark 2.4.0 supports *to_avro* and *from_avro* functions but only for [Scala and Java](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/11/30/apache-avro-as-a-built-in-data-source-in-apache-spark-2-4.html). Then your approach should be fine as long as using appropriate `spark version` and `spark-avro` package.

There is an alternative way that I prefer during using Spark Structure Streaming to consume Kafka message is to use UDF with [`fastavro`](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro) python library. [`fastavro`](https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro) is relative fast as it used C extension. I had been used it for our production for months without any issues.

As denoted in below code snippet, main Kafka message is carried in `values` column of `kafka_df`. For a demonstration purpose, I use a simple avro schema with 2 columns `col1` & `col2`. The return of `deserialize_avro` UDF function is a tuple respective to number of fields described within avro schema. Then write the stream out to console for debugging purpose.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import io
import fastavro

def deserialize_avro(serialized_msg):
    bytes_io = io.BytesIO(serialized_msg)
    bytes_io.seek(0)
    avro_schema = {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "struct",
                    "fields": [
                      {"name": "col1", "type": "long"},
                      {"name": "col2", "type": "string"}
                    ]
                  }

    deserialized_msg = fastavro.schemaless_reader(bytes_io, avro_schema)

    return (    deserialized_msg["col1"],
                deserialized_msg["col2"]
            )

if __name__=="__main__":
  spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("consume kafka message") \
        .getOrCreate()

  kafka_df = spark \
              .readStream \
              .format("kafka") \
              .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka01-broker:9092") \
              .option("subscribe", "topic_name") \
              .option("stopGracefullyOnShutdown", "true") \
              .load()

  df_schema = StructType([
              StructField("col1", LongType(), True),
              StructField("col2", StringType(), True)
          ])

  avro_deserialize_udf = psf.udf(deserialize_avro, returnType=df_schema)
  parsed_df = kafka_df.withColumn("avro", avro_deserialize_udf(psf.col("value"))).select("avro.*")

  query = parsed_df.writeStream.format("console").option("truncate", "true").start()
  query.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Spark version is actually 2.1.1, therefore you cannot use a 2.4.3 version of the spark-avro package included in Spark

You'll need to use the one from Databricks

> Are there any other modules that support reading avro messages streamed from Kafka?

You could use a plain kafka Python library, not Spark